# Can't deserialize json object with Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net

I need to deserialize simple json to Dictionary or something similar

json:

```
{"answer":"ok","hash":"hash123","name":"name123","kills":0,"online":0,"currentTime":"2018-01-06 21:18:30","endDate":"2018-01-06 21:18:30","configUrl":"configUrl123","extend":[]}
```

I have a problem with "extend" array at this json object. It gives me error as my Dictionary is wrong for array.
If i delete it all works fine, but i need to save it.

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);
Console.WriteLine(json["answer"]);
```

Sure i can fix this problem with class, but i can't use it.

Comment: Your array is not a string. Have you tried using an object instead? ex: `.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>`

Comment: Thanks, that work's like i need) And i find a other way with dymanic dynamic d = JObject.Parse(data);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize an array into a string, so that's not going to work. Try using `DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to deserialize it with a known object;

```
public class JsonObject
{
    public string answer { get; set; }
    public string hash { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int kills { get; set; }
    public int online { get; set; }
    public string currentTime { get; set; }
    public string endDate { get; set; }
    public string configUrl { get; set; }
    public List<object> extend { get; set; }
}
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonObject>(jsonStr);
Console.WriteLine(json.answer);
```

If you want to stay with dictionary you should deserialize like `Dictionary<string, object>`, because `extend` key not contains `string`;

```
var jsonDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonStr);
Console.WriteLine(jsonDictionary["answer"]);
```